# What does it mean when bias is a function of the estimated parameter?

Tags: statistics, mean-square-error, parameter-estimation

I generated random samples from some distribution with known parameter $p$ and then based on the samples estimated the real value of $p$. It turned out that bias, MSE and variance are symmetrical around fixed value of $p$ and because they are non-accidental I suppose that the estimator is biased. Is such conclusion correct?

Comment: If you estimated $p$ for a binomial distribution with the constant estimator $\hat p =\frac12$, then I would call this biased as it is biased for all $p$, except for $p=\frac12$ where it is unbiased

Comment: @Henry I used mean success rate estimator